# How to make an image object a link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink

HTML equivalent:

```
<a href='#'> <img src='...'....../></a>
```

Looking for something along the lines of:

```
var im = document.createElement("img");
im.ADDLINK;
```

Relevant code:

```
var close = document.createElement("img");
    close.src="close.png";
    close.width = 50;
    close.height = 50;
    close.border = 1;
    close.className="closeButton";
    close.style.cssFloat="right";

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = "#";
```

Make close image a link:

```
    link.appendChild(close);

    close.style.right=0+"px";
            //Div img is a div created above this code snippet:
    divimg.appendChild(close);
```

Comment: You insert the image to a link element but then you insert only the image to the div. Change the last line to `divimg.appendChild(link);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the link:

```
var link = document.createElement(a);
link.href = "http://...com";
```

Add the image:

```
var im = document.createElement("img");
link.appendChild(im);
```

And append it to the DOM where needed

Comment: Thanks tymeJV, still doesn't work for me though. I'll add code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<script>
   function imgRedirect(destination){

     location.href = destination;

   }
</script>
<img src="..." onclick="imgRedirect('http://google.com')"/>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply cris_dpa, unfortunately it all needs to be done via javascript.